# How to finetune vertical alignment with bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I have a cshtml file that takes care of displaying two buttons below each other in the upper right corner of the screen. Bootstrap 3.3.4 is used.
Now I need to add text to the left of the first button and I managed to do so with the below code, but any vertical alignment is non-existent, as this image shows:

[image: text not nicely aligned with the button to the right of it]

Preferably I'd have the invisible line on which "This is the text" as it were stands lowered to the bottom border of the first button. The second option is to have the text vertically centered relative to the first button, that would be fine as well. How can I accomplish this with bootstrap 3.3.4?

This is the code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: $root.logout">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
        <span data-bind="translate: 'button-logout'"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Relations", new {Area = "Administration"})">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        <span data-bind="translate: 'button-administration'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <span>This is the text&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can help if you can replicate that output in Codesandbox.

Comment: @m4n0 No, I tried,  but I didn't get the desired result. This may be because you cannot set a reference to bootstrap 3.3.4 but only to 4.5.2.

Comment: I'll just add some custom css I guess. That will work anyway. It is a bit of a pity though - this is not why you make use of frameworks.